# Finding the differential of a smooth map

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be the smooth manifold of real $n \times n$ matrices of rank $k$. Let $S$ be the smooth manifold of real $n \times n$ *skew* symmetric matrices.

Consider the function $F: M \to S : A \mapsto A - A^T$. Is $F$ smooth? If so, what is the differential $dF_A$ of $F$ at $A$?

(Manifolds of fixed-rank matrices are described in Proposition 1.14 on page 133 of [*Optimization and Dynamical Systems*](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~john/papers/BOOK/B04.PDF) by Helmke and Moore.)

Comment: Yes, it's smooth; it's polynomial in the coordinates. As for the differential, what are you using as coordinates on the tangent space?

Comment: @JohnHughes Since $S$ is pretty much $\mathbb{R}^{n(n−1)/2}$, I guess a coordinate chart would be $(S,\phi)$ where $\phi$ maps the upper triangle of A to the corresponding vector, that is, $\phi : A \mapsto (a_{12},a_{13},a_{23},...,a_{n−1,n})$. I'm not sure about M.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that $F$ is a smooth map (indeed, polynomial, as @John said) on the vector space $\mathcal M_{n}$ of *all* $n\times n$ matrices (as a mapping to all matrices, yet again). So its restriction to any subset (or submanifold) is smooth.

The best way to compute the differential is *not* to try to work in charts, but to compute directional derivatives; i.e., compute $$dF(A)(B) = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{F(A+tB)-F(A)}t$$ in the vector space setting. The trick will be to decide what a "tangent vector" $B$ to $M\subset \mathcal M_n$ at $A$ will be. What exactly are you trying to compute/decide?

Comment: I'm hoping to use $F$ to show that the set $S'$ of symmetric $n \times n$ matrices of rank $k$ form a submanifold of $M$, since $F^{-1}(0) = S'$.

Comment: Ah, so the best way to do that is to show that the linear subspace of symmetric matrices is transverse to $M$ as submanifolds of $\mathcal M_n$. So the best way to approach it is to express $M$ locally as the preimage of a regular value under an appropriate mapping.

Comment: In the book I mentioned, they say that a tangent vector of $M$ at $A$ has the form $XA + AY$ where $X$ and $Y$ are $n \times n$ matrices.

Comment: How do I know that $M$ is a submanifold of $\mathcal M_n$? Is $F$ an appropriate mapping?

Comment: Assume the upper left $k\times k$ submatrix $A_1$ is invertible, and write $A = \begin{bmatrix} A_1 & B \\ C & D\end{bmatrix}$. Near $A$ the submanifold $M$ is given by $f(A) = D-CA_1^{-1}B=0$. You can check that $0$ is a regular value and, in fact, the book's claim about the tangent space of $M$ at $A$ should follow by choosing nice coordinates and finding $\ker df(A)$.